# TranslateAnimation in Android with adjacent view

Tags: android, android-layout, android-animation

I have a view with TransaleAnimation which works very fine. The problem is view has a android:layout_toRightOf="@id/iv_hook" to an ImageView which doesn't animate with view. Is there any way to achieve this?

Comment: animate both views with the same Translation offset?

Comment: The ImageView is for show/hide. when the view slides out i want 'Show' image to display.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The ImageView is for show/hide. when the view slides out i want 'Show' image to display.

Try something like this:

```
// yourImageView is hidden => its visibility is View.GONE


// animate your view with translation => slide out effect
viewToAnimate.animate().translationX(newTranslationX).setDuration(duration).withEndAction(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        // now, as the animation has just finished, we want to show the image
        yourImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }
}).start();
```